# Set initial value for model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Entity Framework to create my data objects. I have an entity called Users. It contains a property named Code, which is an integer.

The problem is that when I pass a blank User entity to my Create view, and call

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Code) %>
```

the textbox is populated with a 0.

I can't set the property to nullable because the value can't be null in my database. Which means I can't set the value to null in my controller.

What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be binding directly to an EF model, exactly for these types of issues.

EF shouldn't care about UI, and the UI shouldn't care about EF.

The recommended middle-man is always a **ViewModel**.

Setup a ViewModel in your Controller, which should contain a *string property* for the code, which you can bind to (like @Divi says).

When you submit the form, map the ViewModel to the EF model in order to persist to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create a string property on the model and bind the view to that? And in the controller set the actual int property based on the string property?